# Tmux makes a sound when I launch it, how could I disable that?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, tmux

When I launch tmux in the terminal, is causes my Linux Mint to play a sound in the speakers.

The sound is a Linux Mint system sound. Perhaps it's the "alert" sound, but I cannot identify it by name.

The same alert sound plays when I exit tmux.

Any ideas on how to disable this sound when tmux is launched?

Comment: Do you have any of the bell settings in your `.tmux.conf`?

Comment: No, my .tmux.conf file is empty.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, after having enabled/setup the bell in general. It only happens with gnome-terminal, and there's an additional string when exiting tmux: `]112[exited]`. tmux 1.9-6ubuntu1. gnome-terminal 3.6.2-0ubuntu1. Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting either `bell-on-alert [on | off]` (off) or `bell-action [any | none | current]` (none). There's `visual-bell [on | off]` also.

Comment: Dang, none of them made a difference. For example, I set `set-option bell-on-alert off` in `~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: @eoinoc, oh, it does, alas. :)

Comment: @eoinoc, It's really annoying issue looking like a bug, actually…

Comment: Oh, interesting if that's a tmux bug.

Answer (score 0):

The "bell" is launched by your terminal, not tmux!
I use Gnome terminal and could disable it going to EDIT --> Profile Preferences
and unticking "Terminal Bell" (this disable all the bells though)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in `gnome-terminal`.

I've just upgraded to 3.14.0-1 (from Debian testing) and the beep during startup and exit of `tmux` in `gnome-terminal` is gone.

Therefore it's likely to have been fixed since 3.6.2-0ubuntu1 - or there's an Ubuntu patch causing it (which Linux Mint might also use).